# Check if a date is within a date range

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

What is the best way to find out if a date falls within a certain date range? I am doing this right now:

```
if (([rangeStart compare:userEnteredDate] == NSOrderedAscending) && ([rangeEnd compare:userEnteredDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
```

The only problem with the above code is that if the rangeStart date and the userEnteredDate are the same, the if statement would yield "false" for some reason unknown to me. Anyone have any ideas why?

Is there a better way to check if userEnteredDate falls within rangeStart and rangeEnd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there's a more straight forward way, but this one should work.-

```
if (([rangeStart compare:userEnteredDate] == NSOrderedAscending || 
     [rangeStart compare:userEnteredDate] == NSOrderedSame) && 
     ([rangeEnd compare:userEnteredDate] == NSOrderedDescending ||
      [rangeEnd compare:userEnteredDate] == NSOrderedSame))
```

Comment: You can simplify if you consider that checking for the comparison to be equal to `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedSame` is like checking that it's not `NSOrderedDescending`. Same concept applies to the other comparison. A more straightforward way is given in my answer below.

Comment: Mmh you're right. But shouldn't the comparisons be `[rangeStart compare:userEnteredDate]` and `[rangeStart compare:userEnteredDate]`?

Comment: Note that I inverted Ascending and Desceding wrt to yours ;)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that if `rangeStart` is equal to `userEnteredDate`, the first chunk of your boolean expression will evaluate to

```
NSOrderedSame == NSOrderedAscending
```

which is indeed false.

I'd rearrange the order and use something like

```
if (([userEnteredDate compare:rangeStart] != NSOrderedDescending)
     && ([userEnteredDate compare:rangeEnd] != NSOrderedAscending)) {
   //... 
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still did not work. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: The issue was that if the userEnteredDate was the same as rangeStart, the if statement was false. This seemed to prevail with the above code. Your reply was somewhat helpful though because you did mention the reason why it does not work. So, I marked your answer as useful.

Comment: Very weird. If `rangeStart` is equal to `userEnteredDate` the above code will evaluate to `NSOrderedSame != NSOrderedDescending && NSOrderedSame != NSOrderedAscending`, which evaluates to true.